# All insert request in laravel return (500 server error) on Plesk server

Tags: php, laravel, windows, plesk

I upload my **Laravel** project on **Plesk** Server.

**Firstly**, i had (500 server error) on all routes. but i solved this problem when i set (**ROOT directory**) to (**laravel\public**).

But now i have an (500 Server Error) in all **insert requests**. how can solve this problem on Plesk server.

i show on the google the **.htaccess** file don't work on **Plesk server**, so i have to worked on (public/web.config) but i don't have any details how can i deal with the file.
the web.config content:

````
  <system.webServer>
    <rewrite>
      <rules>
        <rule name="Imported Rule 1" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url="^(.*)/$" ignoreCase="false" />
          <conditions>
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" ignoreCase="false" negate="true" />
          </conditions>
          <action type="Redirect" redirectType="Permanent" url="/{R:1}" />
        </rule>
        <rule name="Imported Rule 2" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url="^" ignoreCase="false" />
          <conditions>
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" ignoreCase="false" negate="true" />
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" ignoreCase="false" negate="true" />
          </conditions>
          <action type="Rewrite" url="index.php" />
        </rule>
      </rules>
    </rewrite>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>```
````